# Can't connect to FTP

Tags: troubleshooting, network-access

I am using Beetel 777VR1 with Airtel Broadband. I am trying to connect with a FTP server but I am not able to access that. However  with same credentials when I try to connect with my mobile connection it is successful.

What can be the cause?

Comment: Can you provide some diagnostic information or debugging information, what do you see in your FTP client logs or router logs, can you provide any technical details about the set up at all?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Comment: @RonMaupin Sorry, I forgot to accept. I just upvoted the answer. Accepted it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

open 192.168.1.1 log in to your modem and go to advanced-->nat--->alg--> turn  on FTP and save and you're done